# Sequential Colour Palettes Across Facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm building a dashboard which includes a lollypop graph of top 10 locations by number of visitors, faceted by year. Here is a roughly similar plot I constructed using dummy data:

[image]

To reorder the locations by total number of visitors per facet, [I used reorder_within() and scale_x_reorder(), created by Tyler Rinker](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R). For the sequential colour palette, I used RColorBrewer and scale_color_distiller.

I have three things I'd like to change about colors of the bars, and I'm unsure how to do any of them.

1. I would like the colors to start from a bit darker rather than nearly white, because they're a bit hard to see.
2. I would like each bar to have its own color, even when the visitor count is the same, and to have those colours be clearly distinguishable from each other, while still being sequential.
3. I would like each facet to have the same colour scheme, so it looks consistent - I understand that the scheme differs across the facets because they all have different visitor numbers.

Reproducible example below with some dummy data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

#facet reorder code - by Tyler Rinker
reorder_within <-
  function(x,
           by,
           within,
           fun = mean,
           sep = "___",
           ...) {
    new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
    stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
  }

scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(
    labels = function(x)
      gsub(reg, "", x),
    ...
  )
}


dummy <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(c(2019, 2020, 2021), c(10)),
  Destination = c("loc_4322", "loc_43267", "loc_6786", "loc_43294", "loc_45566", 
                  "loc_1234", "loc_367", "loc_14765", "loc_49865", "loc_90765",
                  "loc_4332", "loc_367", "loc_2112", "loc_596111", "loc_54980",
                  "loc_539", "loc_5699", "loc_1965", "loc_6387", "loc_213",
                  "loc_5245", "loc_4787", "loc_34098", "loc_67609", "loc_50954",
                  "loc_54421", "loc_548901", "loc_23245", "loc_4322", "loc_0986"),
  Visitor_numbers = c(102234, 234984, 39546, 108943, 430985, 243056, 342890,
                      253980, 129803, 134954, 21954, 128904, 223242, 223242, 
                      223242, 23242, 243980, 134324, 542323, 12545, 905334,
                      123434, 123434, 569085, 5085, 235463, 209384, 230923,
                      243089, 120923)
)




destinations <- dummy %>%
  ggplot() +
  (aes(
    x = reorder_within(Destination, -Visitor_numbers, Year),
    y = Visitor_numbers,
    color = Visitor_numbers
  )) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = reorder_within(Destination, -Visitor_numbers, Year),
      xend = reorder_within(Destination, -Visitor_numbers, Year),
      y = 0,
      yend = Visitor_numbers
    ),
    size = 2
  ) +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_color_distiller(type = "seq", palette = "Oranges", direction = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ Year,
             dir = "v",
             scales = "free",
             ncol = 1) +
  coord_flip()

destinations
```

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your #3. It already looks to me like each facet has the same color scheme, and they look consistent. Are you saying that you want to maintain that aspect as the changes for #1 and #2 are done, or is #3 a change that I'm missing?

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I was a little ambigious. I understand that the last bar in facet 3, for example, is much darker than the rest because the number of visitors in loc_5245 is significantly higher than any other location in the plot. I'd just like the colours to look consistent across all 3 facets. I think if the rest of the bars were more distinguishable from each other, it wouldn't matter so much, since you otherwise have many bars of nigh-indistinguishable colours, and only 1 or 2 really dark ones.

Comment: To simplify, I just want each bar per facet to be a distinguishably different colour, while still being sequential with Visitor_numbers.

Comment: What is the distribution of those values? If it's lognormal it might make more sense to map the color to `log10(Visitor_number)`

Comment: Or of you just want to give each line in the set a unique color, you could map `color` to `seq_along(Destination)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest coloring by rank or scaled value within year. Below are two possibilities:

```
destinations <- dummy %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(Visitor_numbers_rank = min_rank(Visitor_numbers)) %>%
  #mutate(Visitor_numbers_scaled = Visitor_numbers/max(Visitor_numbers)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = reorder_within(Destination, -Visitor_numbers, Year),
    y = Visitor_numbers,
    color = Visitor_numbers_rank
  )) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  ...
```

[image]

To modify the color palette to darken the lightest values, you could expand the color limits to include values less than any of your data, effectively shifting the colors to start farther up the scale. I know rank doesn't go below 1, so having the color scale start at -5 will shift everything along.

```
  scale_color_distiller(type = "seq", palette = "Oranges",  direction = 1,
                        limits = c(-5, NA)) +
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and effective!

Comment: Fantastic - thank you so much!